# xdg-open only opens a new tab in a new Chromium window despite passing it a URL

Tags: chromium, xdg-open

When I am using `xdg-open` to open a link in Chromium, it just results in a new Chromium window with only the new tab page, with nothing else.

For example, `xdg-open 'https://askubuntu.com'` will just open a new Chromium window and won't open up AskUbuntu.

It just seems that the URL isn't being passed to Chromium, as invoking Chromium directly *does* work and opens the desired page: `chromium-browser 'https://askubuntu.com'` *works*.

Obviously, Chromium is the default browser.

Where could the problem be, and how can I fix that? It is especially annoying when some programs use `xdg-open` to open a link and you can't go to the page you want, or even see what was opened.

Comment: Although this question is for Chromium, this might work for Firefox if it is the same issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is indeed that `xdg-open` does not pass the requested URL to Chromium, so instead of running `chromium-browser url-here`, it is executing `chromium-browser` which just opens a new window.

After searching on the Internet, I found out that `xdg-open` uses some "config" files located in `/usr/share/applications`.

`/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop` seemed to be correct, as it is configured to pass the URL to Chromium correctly:

```
$ grep Exec /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
Exec=chromium-browser %U
...
```

So what was wrong? It turns out that there's another location which `xdg-open` uses and that has priority over `/usr/share/applications`.

```
$ grep Exec ~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
Exec=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --use-system-title-bar --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=14.0.0.125
```

I have no idea as to why there's another chromium-browser.desktop, but note that this Exec line does not pass the URL; it is missing the `%U`. So I simply appended `%U` to this line. This instantly fixed all issues with `xdg-open` and Chromium.

Comment: Incredible! I've been beating my head against a brick wall for weeks on this one, barely found this answer. Same thing happens with the `google-chrome` package. How did you figure it out?

Comment: I had this issue for a long time too, and I only found the cause when I happened to read about `.desktop` application files -- I remembered the issues with Chromium and decided to check the files, and that's how I got it fixed.

Comment: Ultimately, I think that the issue was caused by pepperflash, although I'm not sure. Need to look at the package file list or install script to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, worked for google-chrome by updating ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop

Comment: Moved chrome-related files from /.local/share/applications and it started working instantly! Thanks!